# How to create entries in List and send notifications to different user groups (depending on type of notification)?

Tags: list, permissions, alert

In our SharePoint 2013 site collection, we have a list with "news" where we create an entry for each message.
The users can get notifications via Alerts.

Is it possible to create sub-folders in this list with the following permissions:

1 List
1.1 subfolder 1 - reading permissions for group A
1.2 subfolder 2 - reading permissions for group B
1.3 subfolder 3 - reading permssions for group A AND group B

*Question about alerts:*
If the users from group A and group B set an alert on this list, will users of group A only notfied by their alert about changes in subfolders 1 and 3 and users of group B will not receive an alert, if something changes in subfolder 1?